# How to punctuate an INSERT statement that uses FROM_UNIXTIME

Tags: mysql, datetime, python

In a **Python** environment, I've got the following variable:

```
post_time_ms="1581546697000"
```

which is a Unix-style time with milliseconds.

In my table, "created_date_time" is defined as a datetime column.

I'm trying to use an INSERT statement of the form:

```
sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO myTable (id_string, text,
 created_date_time) VALUES ('identifier', 'text_content',
 FROM_UNIXTIME('post_time/1000')"
```

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to punctuate that.  If I run the query as shown above, I get:

```
"Failed to insert record 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: 'post_time/1000'
```

I've tried every variation of single quotes/no quotes I can think of but I always get errors.

For example if I do:

```
sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO myTable (id_string, text,
 created_date_time) VALUES ('identifier', 'text_content',
 FROM_UNIXTIME('post_time'/1000)"
```

I get:

```
Failed to insert record 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'post_time'
```

I've gone so far as to try and convert the Unix-style "1581546697000" value as follows:

```
post_time_mysql = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(post_time)/1000)
```

and then:

```
sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO myTable (id_string, text,
 created_date_time) VALUES ('identifier', 'text_content',
 'post_time_mysql')"
```

and even though

```
print(post_time_mysql)
```

outputs "2020-02-14 09:25:28",

I still get this error for the above query:

```
Failed to insert record 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: 'post_time_mysql' for column `myDatabase`.`myTable`.`created_date_time` at row 1
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

==========

My workaround is to do the following:

```
sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO myTable (id_string, text, created_date_time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

sql_insert_data = (identifier, text_content, post_time_mysql)

cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, sql_insert_data)
```

But I still don't understand how to successfully do it with one query statement - if it's possible.

Comment: I think you need to find some tutorial that explains how to use Python variables in SQL statements in whatever library you're using (for some reason you chose not to show your code, so I can't be more specific than that).

Comment: Well I tried to include the code that I thought was relevant to the question without including a lot of code that isn't relevant.  I included the line showing how I defined the variable "post_time_mysql" and I showed how I was using that variable in the INSERT query.  And I showed that a print statement outputs a string that looks like it is correctly formatted for a DATETIME column.  Not sure what else one would need to assess the issue.

Comment: You said the variable holding the timestamp was called `post_time_ms` how come non of the queries use that variable

Comment: Your error message talks about problems with `tweet_post_time` but No such field/column exists in the query?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yep, my bad for mixing up a couple different versions of code when posting the question.  I've edited the post so that `tweet_post_time` is consistently referred to as `post_time`.  Apologies.

Comment: Print out the python variable `sql_insert_query` -- this should show the problem.